# Swift: Encrypting messages after facebook login?

Tags: swift, security, encryption

I am developing an app which uses Facebook login, and which contains a messaging platform. Messages are stored in a Firebase database, and I would like to have some sort of encryption such that the database stores the encrypted messages, and only the sender and receiver can decrypt them.

I know the sender/receiver need some unique key to encrypt/decrypt the messages, but I am unsure as to how I should generate this key, and as to where it should be stored? Basically, there are plenty of tutorials on message encrypting, so I am wondering about the general information structure of an app which involves this kind of encryption, rather than about what exact code to implement!

I thought about basing the encryption key on a user's Facebook access token, but these change every 60 days so I assume it wouldn't work?

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: This is a very broad question.  What you are looking for is E2EE.  End-to-end Encryption.  Implementing this correctly is incredibly difficult and requires a large amount of in-depth cryptography knowledge.  An approach around ECDHE with ECDSA preserves Forward Secrecy and obviously can't be MITMed, even by your own server.  This technique is arguably one of the most secure TLS suites available currently.  I'd start there.

Comment: Seeing as ATS (app transport security) requires TLS 1.2, any communication done through HTTPS, which I don't think you can otherwise, should have enough general encryption unless you are looking to keep your firebase records encrypted from even yourself.

Comment: I also think that this is a very very broad question. You should start by reading up about existing protocols like Signal, and then you can decide whether the tradeoffs sound acceptable.